# How to get the name of an object that is inside another object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project to open up custom dialogue boxes.
I'm trying to make it so in the `settings` object, you can specify the custom buttons' names as the names of objects, with the button's info inside. I am wondering, how *do* I get the name of the buttons' names?

My current code that I have is this:

```
function resetTools() {
    Dialogue.open({
        message: "Are you sure you want to reset all chat rooms?",
        buttons: {
            yes: {
                styleSheetClass: "dangerbtn",
                onclick: function() {
                    // Do stuff here
                }
            },
            no: {
                onclick: function() {
                    // Do other stuff here
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

var Dialogue = {
    open: function(settings) {
        var message = settings.message;
        var buttons = message.buttons;
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            var cls  = buttons[i].styleSheetClass.length ? buttons[i].styleSheetClass + " dialogueButton" : "dialogueButton";
            $(".dialogue .buttons").append('<div class="' + cls + '">' +  +'</div>');
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: don't you mean `var buttons = settings.buttons;`?

Comment: Wouldn't the variable i have the name of the button you are currently looping over?

Comment: @sqykly Wait... I do. Woops.

Comment: oh, and there is no `buttons.length` since it's a plain object, not an array.

Comment: which speaks to your problem in general.  The names are property keys.  Use those.

Comment: ... and, I can't edit my post ... @sqykly So, how would I loop over it?

Comment: how ES6-compliant is your browser?

Comment: @sqykly It is the newest version of Waterfox...

Comment: My answer works ES5 and up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `for...in` loop to get an object's keys, and remember to use `hasOwnProperty` to test for a property's existence

```
for (var key in buttons) {
  if (buttons.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // key could be 'yes' or 'no'
    // access the value using buttons[key]
  }
}
```

Or you can use `Object.keys` which is introduced in es5.1

```
Object.keys(buttons).forEach(function(key) {
  // do something with buttons[key]
})
```

Comment: I have had a lot of good answers, but since you @Li have answered earliest, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Object.keys()` on `settings.button.yes`

```
var Dialogue = {
    open: function(settings) {
        var message = settings.message;
        var buttons = setting.buttons.yes;
        Object.keys(buttons).forEach(function(button) {
          if (button === "styleSheetClass") {
            var cls  = buttons[button].length 
                       ? buttons[button] + " dialogueButton" 
                       : "dialogueButton";
            $(".dialogue .buttons")
            .append('<div class="' + cls + '">' +  +'</div>');
          }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes...

First is

`var buttons = message.buttons`;

Which will make the `buttons` to be `undefined`.

It should be

`var buttons = settings.buttons;`

Next, since your `buttons` is an object you will need a `for..in` loop to extract key names..

So at the end of the day your code should look

```
var Dialogue = {
    open: function(settings) {
        var message = settings.message;
        var buttons = settings.buttons; // <<<< NOTE: It's settings.buttons.
        for (var button in buttons) {
            console.log(button); // This will give you yes in 1st iteration and no in 2nd.
            var cls  = buttons[button].styleSheetClass.length ? buttons[button].styleSheetClass + " dialogueButton" : "dialogueButton";
            $(".dialogue .buttons").append('<div class="' + cls + '">' +  +'</div>');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object.keys(buttons).forEach(function (name) {
    var button = buttons[name];
    // now you have both
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a problem on line 24 (25 in this snippet). You're using `buttons` as if it were an array.

```js
function resetTools() {
    Dialogue.open({
        message: "Are you sure you want to reset all chat rooms?",
        buttons: {
            yes: {
                styleSheetClass: "dangerbtn",
                onclick: function() {
                    // Do stuff here
                }
            },
            no: {
                onclick: function() {
                    // Do other stuff here
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

var Dialogue = {
    open: function(settings) {
        var message = settings.message;
        var buttons = settings.buttons;
        //                           vvv buttons isn't an array, it's an object
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            var cls  = buttons[i].styleSheetClass.length ? buttons[i].styleSheetClass + " dialogueButton" : "dialogueButton";
            $(".dialogue .buttons").append('<div class="' + cls + '">' +  +'</div>');
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a fix:

```js
function resetTools() {
    Dialogue.open({
        message: "Are you sure you want to reset all chat rooms?",
        buttons: [
            {
              name: 'Yes',
              styleSheetClass: "dangerbtn",
              onclick: function() {
                // Do stuff here
              }
            }, {
              name: 'No',
              onclick: function() {
                // Do stuff here
              }
            },
        ]
    })
}

var Dialogue = {
    open: function(settings) {
        var message = settings.message;
        var buttons = message.buttons;
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            var cls  = buttons[i].styleSheetClass != undefined ? buttons[i].styleSheetClass + " dialogueButton" : "dialogueButton";
            $(".dialogue .buttons").append('<div class="' + cls + '">' + buttons[i].name +'</div>');
        }
    }
}
```

I've tweaked the object that the dialogue is opened with to have buttons as an array with the name as a property of each object in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and do it like this:

```
$.each(buttons, function(button_name, button) {
    // code ...
});
```

Or without jQuery:

```
var keys = Object.keys(buttons);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var button_name = keys[i];
    var button = buttons[button_name];

    // code ...
}
```

Object.keys gives you names of elements in this object.

You can use `console.log(Object.keys(buttons))` to preview it.